# How to center the last widget in Gridview.count() in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development

In my app, I putted widgets in Gridview.count() in two columns in portrait mode:

[image]

And it become three columns in landscape mode:

[image]

I want the last widget to be in the center in both portrait and landscape modes

Here's the Gridview.count() code:

```
SizedBox(
              height: context.isPortrait ? 660 : 610,
              child: GridView.count(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding:
                    context.isPortrait ? portraitPadding : landscapePadding,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                crossAxisCount: context.isPortrait ? 2 : 3,
                children: const [
                  Divisions(
                    image: '${kImagesPath}person.png',
                    title: 'ولي الأمر',
                  ),
                  Divisions(
                    image: '${kImagesPath}employing.png',
                    title: 'طلب توظيف',
                  ),
                  Divisions(
                    image: '${kImagesPath}links.png',
                    title: 'روابط عامة',
                  ),
                  Divisions(
                    image: '${kImagesPath}interview.png',
                    title: 'طلب مقابلة',
                  ),
                  Divisions(
                    image: '${kImagesPath}form.png',
                    title: 'نماذج',
                  ),
                  Divisions(
                    image: '${kImagesPath}calendar.png',
                    title: 'رزنامة العام',
                  ),
                  Divisions(
                    image: '${kImagesPath}call.png',
                    title: 'تواصل معنا',
                    // right: context.isPortrait ? -125 : -85,
                    // left: context.isPortrait ? -15 : -16,
                    // bottom: context.isPortrait ? -10 : 30,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

Before your last `Divisions` you can add this

`if (orientation == Orientation.landscape) Container(),`

This if statement checks if you display in portrait mode then it adds on its left a Container(), only as a placeholder.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/hMpCADS.jpg The element type 'Set<Container>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the brackets and it worked! But still not centered in portrait mode

Comment: Can you center the widget in portrait mode?

Comment: Dont use MediaQuery to find the orientation of your screen. Doesn't work in all cases. Instead, wrap your GridView with OrientationBuilder. https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/orientation

After you use OrientationBuilder, then it will work as it should.

Comment: Also nothing happened, still not centered

Comment: Can you your code here ?

Comment: https://github.com/ahmloutfy/Pure-Soft-Training-Responsive/blob/PureSoftTrainingResponsive/lib/screens/home_page.dart

Comment: Check this. https://codeshare.io/EBLEEX . You have to put your OrientationBuilder as high as possible in you widget. Also notice how orientation is checked, without using context, but instead, with what the OrientationBuilder provides

Comment: https://codeshare.io/EBLEEX link not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250112/discussion-between-a-ktns-and-ahmed-loutfy).